# Load several Images without label in keras cnn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I have several .jpeg images with different names, that I want to load into a cnn in a jupyter notebook to have them classified. The only way I found was:

```
test_image = image.load_img("name_of_picute.jpeg",target_size=(64,64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result = cnn.predict(test_image)
```

All the other things found at the Keras API like `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()`seems to only work on labeled data. Sadly I can't "simply" iterate over the name of the pictures a they are named differently, is there a way to predict all of them at once without naming every single picture?

Thanks for yout help,

Nick

Comment: you could use `os.listdir` if all you pictures are in the same directory, or use `glob`.

Comment: That did work combined with a for loop, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` can be updated to return the dataset and the image_path as explained here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63725072/4994352

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, for larger data it is useful to use a `tf.data.DataSet` as it can be tweaked for performance quite easily. I will give you the non-performance-optimized code. Replace `<YOUR PATH INCL. REGEX>` with the path like `../input/pokemon-images-and-types/images/*/*`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.data.experimental import AUTOTUNE


def load(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    
    ... # do some preprocessing like resizing if necessary

    return img


list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str('<YOUR PATH INCL. REGEX>'), shuffle=True)  # Get all images from subfolders
train_dataset = list_ds.take(-1)
# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```